# Are the posters within Portal 2 available as a resource?

Tags: portal-2

I would like a copy of some of the safety signs/posters within Portal.  Are they available within the Portal 2 folder somewhere?

Example poster: "Know your paradoxes! In the event of a rogue AI ..."

Comment: Unfortunately, the Portal 2 engine uses a different version of their texture format, so you won't be able to open them for the forseeable future, until the tools are updated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While Arda Xi's comment seems to imply that you won't be able to grab them from the game folder, [this guy on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/user/OhMyGodTheresASni) and [this guy](http://www.reddit.com/user/BHCS) [have](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/gwdtn/my_favorite_portal_2_hires_poster_now_in_vector/) [been](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/gvwba/second_portal_2_highres_poster_paradoxes/) [uploading](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/gvqna/im_making_highres_portal_2_posters_just_finished/) hi-res images of the posters somehow(perhaps recreating them themselves?), so if you want them, here are a few:

[image: Paradoxes]
[image: Accidents Hurt]
[image: Future You]

Also, if you're interested in buying prints of the posters, Valve is selling them in the Valve store: here are [the underground posters](http://store.valvesoftware.com/product.php?i=PCP22), [the 1940s posters](http://store.valvesoftware.com/product.php?i=P2213), and [the "My boss is a robot"](http://store.valvesoftware.com/product.php?i=P2215).

Comment: The post accompanying those files include an Illustrator source file. In other words, he has been recreating them himself. Pretty impressive, to be honest.

Comment: By the way, two of those posters were made by BHCS, not the guy you linked.

Comment: @Arda Strange, could have sworn I saw him post the other two as well. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out I was wrong. Someone uploaded all of the posters to their imgur account.
Here's the link: http://rancidmilkman.imgur.com/all/

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  There are plenty of here but the images in the accepted solution are higher res.

Comment: @Haphazard That's because the ones in the accepted solution have been recreated in vector. As such, they're not completely true to the original (although they're pretty damn close). The ones I linked were pulled directly from the game.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has posted most, if not all, of the Portal 2 posters here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srb9I.jpg